# Why does the pushButton.connect() only work in a different class

Tags: python, pyqt6

I want to call a startMeasurement() and stopMeasurement() method by clicking a button in my UI. Only "measurement stopped" is printed when I click the buttons. "connected" is printed, so I assume the connection works. No errors are thrown. Why can't I get "measurement started" to print by pressing the pushButton_start?

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from gui_config import *

from PyQt6 import QtCore as QtCore
from PyQt6 import QtGui
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QFrame,
)


#################################################### _VIEW ####################################################
class UI_SensorMonitor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Sensor Monitor")

        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGTH)
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self._createMainControl()

        self.line = QFrame()
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)

    def _createMainControl(self):
        # add labels
        self.main_control = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label_status = QLabel()
        self.label_status.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.label_status.setText("Status")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_status.setFont(font)

        self.label_status_value = QLabel()
        self.label_status_value.setFont(font)

        self.main_control.addWidget(self.label_status)
        self.main_control.addWidget(self.label_status_value)

        # add buttons
        self.pushButton_start = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_pause = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_abort = QPushButton()

        self.pushButton_start.setText("Start")
        self.pushButton_pause.setText("Pause")
        self.pushButton_abort.setText("Abbrechen")

        # self.pushButton_pause.setFlat(True)

        self.main_control.addWidget(self.pushButton_start)
        self.main_control.addWidget(self.pushButton_pause)
        self.main_control.addWidget(self.pushButton_abort)

        # add control_layout to cent
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(self.main_control)

    # updates the displayed values
    def changeValues(self, values):
        self.label_status_value.setText(values["status"])

    # for testing purposes
    def updateValues(self):
        if self.label_status_value.text() == "ok":
            values = {"status": "Not ok"}
            self.changeValues(values)
        else:
            values = {"status": "ok"}
            self.changeValues(values)


#################################################### Controller ####################################################


class Controller:
    """Controller for connecting MODEL and VIEW"""

    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self.model = model
        self._view = view
        
        self._connectSystemSignals()
        self._createValueUpdateTimer()

    def _connectSystemSignals(self):
        self._view.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self._startMeasurement)
        self._view.pushButton_pause.clicked.connect(self.model._pauseMeasurement)
        self._view.pushButton_abort.clicked.connect(self._abort_action)
        print("connected")

    def _createValueUpdateTimer(self):
        self._view.qTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self._view.qTimer.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVALL)
        self._view.qTimer.timeout.connect(self._view.updateValues)
        self._view.qTimer.start()
    
    def _startMeasurement(self):
        print("measurement started")
        # self._view.pushButton_start.setFlat(True)
        # self._view.pushButton_pause.setFlat(False)

 

    def _abort_action(self):
        print("abort button triggered")




#################################################### Model ####################################################


class ApiInterface:
    def _pauseMeasurement(self):
        print("measurement stoped")
        # self._view.pushButton_start.setFlat(False)
        # self._view.pushButton_pause.setFlat(True)
    pass


#################################################### Main ####################################################


def main():
    values = {"status": "ok"}
    SensorApp = QApplication([])
    SensorWindow = UI_SensorMonitor()
    SensorWindow.show()
    Controller(model=ApiInterface, view=SensorWindow)
    sys.exit(SensorApp.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am a beginner to python and trying to build my first pyQT GUI. I refered to this tutorial:
https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/#creating-a-calculator-app-with-python-and-pyqt

In the sample code the button connection works:

```
"""PyCalc is a simple calculator built with Python and PyQt."""

import sys
from functools import partial

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

ERROR_MSG = "ERROR"
WINDOW_SIZE = 235
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 35
BUTTON_SIZE = 40


class PyCalcWindow(QMainWindow):
    """PyCalc's main window (GUI or view)."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyCalc")
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE)
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self._createDisplay()
        self._createButtons()

    def _createDisplay(self):
        self.display = QLineEdit()
        self.display.setFixedHeight(DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.display)

    def _createButtons(self):
        self.buttonMap = {}
        buttonsLayout = QGridLayout()
        keyBoard = [
            ["7", "8", "9", "/", "C"],
            ["4", "5", "6", "*", "("],
            ["1", "2", "3", "-", ")"],
            ["0", "00", ".", "+", "="],
        ]

        for row, keys in enumerate(keyBoard):
            for col, key in enumerate(keys):
                self.buttonMap[key] = QPushButton(key)
                self.buttonMap[key].setFixedSize(BUTTON_SIZE, BUTTON_SIZE)
                buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMap[key], row, col)

        self.generalLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

    def setDisplayText(self, text):
        """Set the display's text."""
        self.display.setText(text)
        self.display.setFocus()

    def displayText(self):
        """Get the display's text."""
        return self.display.text()

    def clearDisplay(self):
        """Clear the display."""
        self.setDisplayText("")


def evaluateExpression(expression):
    """Evaluate an expression (Model)."""
    try:
        result = str(eval(expression, {}, {}))
    except Exception:
        result = ERROR_MSG
    return result


class PyCalc:
    """PyCalc's controller class."""

    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self._evaluate = model
        self._view = view
        self._connectSignalsAndSlots()

    def _calculateResult(self):
        result = self._evaluate(expression=self._view.displayText())
        self._view.setDisplayText(result)

    def _buildExpression(self, subExpression):
        if self._view.displayText() == ERROR_MSG:
            self._view.clearDisplay()
        expression = self._view.displayText() + subExpression
        self._view.setDisplayText(expression)

    def _connectSignalsAndSlots(self):
        for keySymbol, button in self._view.buttonMap.items():
            if keySymbol not in {"=", "C"}:
                button.clicked.connect(
                    partial(self._buildExpression, keySymbol)
                )
        self._view.buttonMap["="].clicked.connect(self._calculateResult)
        self._view.display.returnPressed.connect(self._calculateResult)
        self._view.buttonMap["C"].clicked.connect(self._view.clearDisplay)


def main():
    """PyCalc's main function."""
    pycalcApp = QApplication([])
    pycalcWindow = PyCalcWindow()
    pycalcWindow.show()
    PyCalc(model=evaluateExpression, view=pycalcWindow)
    sys.exit(pycalcApp.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What do I overlook? Any other tips are also welcome.

Comment: The controller instance gets garbage collected because no reference is kept for it. Change to `controller = Controller(model=ApiInterface, view=SensorWindow)`. In the original code it works because it internally creates closures to the connections (an aspect that, unfortunately, that tutorial seriously overlooks). Also, for future reference, try to do more efforts in providing [mre]s for your questions, and reserve capitalized names only for classes and constants, not variables (see [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)).